# Input field in home page custom components

Tags: home-page-component

Is there anyway to include an input box in the home custom components, preferably at left hand side panel of the salesforce.

Updated after Dan's comment:
Following is the code I am using.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="ScorecardConfig__c">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Penetration threshold">
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel" />
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:inputField value="{!ScorecardConfig__c.Independent_CP_penetration_threshold__c}" label="Ind CP"/>
      <apex:inputField value="{!ScorecardConfig__c.NEC_CP_penetration_threshold__c}" label="NEC CP"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: It is possible,
But it requires you to develop a custom VF page. There you can include an input box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You'd need to create a Visualforce Page and use a Standard Controller or Custom Controller to perform the logic you want, then you can include that page as a component in the sidebar. The Page doesn't need to be special, something like this would be enough:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="My_Object__c">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel" />
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:inputField value="{!My_Object__c.My_First_Field__c}" />
      <apex:inputField value="{!My_Object__c.My_Second_Field__c}" />
      <apex:inputField value="{!My_Object__c.My_Last_Field__c}" />
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Obviously this is just a standard Visualforce Page, nothing fancy.

**Step 1**

Start by going to:

> Setup > Customise > Home > Home Page Components

Under *Custom Components*, click <kbd>New</kbd>, give it a name and choose *Visualforce Area*.

Select the Component Position you want, probably *Narrow (Left) Column* and select your Visualforce Page from the list. You'll then, set the height (in pixels) and then select if you want to have a scrollbar (in case of Overflow) and if you want to display the label.

**Step 2**

Finally, you'll need to add it to the relevant Home Page Layout. To do this, go to:

> Setup > Customise > Home > Home Page Layouts

Press <kbd>Edit</kbd> next to the Layout you want to include the component for, then select the checkbox next to the component you created in Step 1.

Comment: Thanks Dan. But how to pass the value from 'My_Object__c.My_First_Field__c' to the apex class so that when sforce.apex.execute("RestClient", "mymethod", {}); executes it send the 'My_First_Field__c' value to the mymethod (which is in my apex class)

Comment: I guess what you were saying is, that after clicking the Save button on the Visualforce page the value gets stored in the custom object. Then I will write a logic at my end to retrieve the value from that object and use it wherever i want. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Gagan That depends on what it is your doing. If all you're doing is creating records, something akin to the Visualforce Page would do. If you use a Standard Controller as the example shows, you'll be able to use [standard actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_actions.htm) such as Save, Cancel, Edit etc... But you're right, you could create a record and execute an action of the back of that to make a REST callout.

Comment: I have done whatever was mentioned in the above post but i am stuck at a point. In my home page layout, i have added the visualforce page. But it not showing the input fields rather the apex code you mentioned above. Or in other words, it is not showing the preview of the code but the code itself. Anything i am missing?

Comment: @Gagan Can you include your code in your question? Just edit it above.

Comment: It is going under the review. May be because I dont have enough reputation yet.
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="ScorecardConfig__c">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Penetration threshold">
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel" />
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:inputField value="{!ScorecardConfig__c.Independent_CP_penetration_threshold__c}" label="Ind CP"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Comment: I am able to preview it and it is looking fine. But when I see it on my home page. It just shows the code.

Comment: Any clue on how to correct it?

Comment: @Gagan Take a look at the below to see if it helps? https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000094wIIAQ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57348/discussion-between-gagan-and-dan-jones).